# How to load more rows from mysql query for infinite scrolling when using ORDER BY

Tags: php, mysql

I am selecting rows from a mysql dB and showing them in abtches of 20 using infinite scrolling. This all works fine using the row id. I get each batch based on the id of last row shown.

The issue is that I need to use ORDER BY price (not id) when displaying the results. When i use this, the second batch cant load as the ids get mixed up by the ORDER BY price.

Does anyone know how I can get use ORDER BY price rather than by id.

Here is my code - `index.php`

```
$limit = '20';  

jQuery.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url:'getData.php',
                data:'id='+lastID,
                beforeSend:function(){
                    jQuery('.load-more').show();
                },
                success:function(html){
                    jQuery('.load-more').remove();
                    jQuery('#postList').append(html);
                }
            });


$query = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM tablename ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT $limit");
```

Here is `getData.php`

```
$lastID = $_POST['id']; //from above query
$query = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE id > ".$lastID." ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT ".$limit);
```

Comment: add `offset` to your `limit`

Comment: and use placeholder instead of direct value in your query

Comment: Assuming `id` is unique: Use `ORDER BY price,id` to get a stable order. Use `OFFSET` (explicit or as part of `LIMIT`) to get other slices.

Comment: tks guys - will give it a go

Comment: a question for each new batch of 20 results, how would i use offset to tell it where to do the limit from as each scroll adds 20 more?

Comment: You have to offset by the page number that you're trying to show times 20??

Comment: unfortunately i am using infinite scrolling and have no page number. I need to count each time I get a batch of results to use the offset. Any ideas on how I can count each time a batch is added?

Comment: Finally figured it - I added a counter to the jquery and then multiplied it by 20 for the offset - tks guys